# PHP: Permutations of 26 letters in X characters

Tags: php, math, statistics, combinatorics

I have an alphabet array with 26 characters A..Z .

I am searching for a performant algorithm that lists all permutations that fill an array of length X without any repeating characters.

Examples:

X=3 . Target array: _ _ _

Permutations are A B C until Z Y X .

X=4 . Target array: _ _ _ _

Permutations are A B C D until Z Y X W

X=5 . Target array: _ _ _ _ _

Permutations are A B C D E until Z Y X W V

(Sorry, I don't know how this kind of algorithm is named)

Thanks in advance.

Code in C, Delphi or Java is also OK, since it can be easy translated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are we doing your homework? You seem to understand the question, how much time have you spent trying to come up with the solution yourself?

Comment: "Sorry, I don't know how this kind of algorithm is named"  I believe the magic word you're looking for is "lexicographic".

Comment: I am not doing "homework" for school (ahmet added the tag), I need this algorithm for a private project. I have searched a lot for performant algorithms, but only found algorithms that permutate a 26-array. I have also tried it myself, but it is not performant, neither dynamic for unknown X.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is a recursive one

```
char current_combination[27];
int char_used[26];

void enumerate(int i, int n)
{
    for (int j=0; j<26; j++)
    {
        if (!char_used[j])
        {
            char_used[j] = 1;
            current_combination[i] = 'A' + j;
            if (i+1 == n)
            {
                puts(current_combination);
            }
            else
            {
                enumerate(i+1, n);
            }
            char_used[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The function above accepts the index `i` of the character to be computed and the total number `n` of characters in a combination (the code assumes `i<n`). It keeps the current combination and the array of flags for already used variables in globals to avoiding copying them around.

To generate for example all combinations of length 5 call `enumerate(0, 5)`.

Note that the total number of combinations grows **very** fast. For example for `n=6` there are `165,765,600` combinations, with more than 1Gb of output.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a simple brute force approach though do understand the number of permutations can get up there as the number is 26!/(26-x)! which can be rather large as for 3 there are 15,600 permutations and for 5 there are 7,893,600 permutations which isn't exactly small.  Basically you could just loop through all the values with loops in loops that unfortunately would be O(n^x) where x is the number of characters since the nesting of loops causing the complexity jump.

---

Something to consider is how finely are you examining complexity here.  For example, while you could consider ways to go about being clever in the first pair of loops to avoid duplication, the third loop in becomes a bit trickier though if you started with a List of 26 letters and removed the previous ones, this would make the last loop be a simply iterative as you know there isn't any duplicates though this can be expensive in terms of memory consumed in having to make copies of the list on each pass from the outer loop.  Thus the first time, you'd go through AB_ and then AC_ and so forth, but the copying of the list may be where this gets expensive in terms of operations as there would be thousands of times that the list is copied that one could wonder if that is more efficient than doing comparisons.

Comment: @symcbean: JB King is right. On first step we have 26 variants to be selected, on second 25, on X's step 26-X+1 variant. So if we need X-chars sequence, we have 26*25*..*(26-X+1) combinations of such string, or 26!/(26-X)! combinations. Note that characters mustn't repeats.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The idea of nested FOR loops including IF clauses that check if the letter already appeared in the previous for-states is good, but I dont know if it is the most performant way to iterate from ABC through ZYX, especially for greater X.

Comment: @RP: yes, if the resultant set is to be X chars long - but the OP is looking for all possible combinations - i.e. the combinations are \sum_{X=0}^{X=26}{26!/(26-X)!} which is >> 26!/(26-X)! for any value of X > 0

Comment: @DM: no IF statement required.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to see all permutations? If you have X=3, you will have 26*25*24 combinations = 15600. And if X=5 number of combinations is equal to 7893600.

You need to randomly select one letter(or array index) and store it somewhere and on each iteration you should check if this letter(or index) has been already selected on one of the previous iteration. After this you will get random sequence which length is X characters. You need to store it too. Then you need to reapeat all operation made on the previous step and also you have to check if there is random sequense with subsequence you have been generating now.

Or you could use direct enumeration.

Sorry for not satisfactory english. I tried to be clear.

I hope it will be usefull.